# How to deal with side panes in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to navigate amazon product pages. When my script tries to add a product to cart, sometimes a side pane will appear, asking whether I want to add a warranty before adding to cart.

This is my add to cart process:

```
browser.find_element_by_name('submit.add-to-cart').click()

browser.switch_to.frame(browser.find_element_by_id('checkoutPrefetch'))
```

The second line is my attempt to treat the side pane as an iframe and switch to it. But I get a "cannot find id error."
So far, I have been unable to find a way to interact with the buttons on the side pane.

The side pane contains the following html lines:

```
div id="attach-desktop-sideSheet" class="a-section attach-desktop-sidesheet" style="right:0px;"
input id = "attachSIDeprecated" type="hidden" value=""
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: HI @Capcoil, welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is clear and short, that's good. Maybe you can add the code which is (sometimes) working and also show the issue of the side-pane somehow? Here's the guide on [ask], please read it through. Thanks!

Comment: Try to incorporate it into the question to create a clear overview for the people who might have the answers. The better the question is asked, the more it will attract the right people with the answers.

Comment: You should be more specific